# If the apache Drill can execute update, delete ,insert operations

Tags: apache, hadoop, apache-drill

As we known that apache drill can easy to query , but I have some questions as followings :

**First :**

If the apache Drill can execute update, delete ,insert operations on   HDFS .

**Second :**

If the first question's answer is yes , how can I use apache Drill to update, or to delete, or to insert data on HDFS .

Answer (score 2):

Apache Drill cannot insert, update, or delete data that currently exists on HDFS.

You can execute a Create Table AS (CTAS) statement to create a new data set.

Some examples of its use are given [here](http://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas/).