# UPDATE/INSERT when modifying RDBMSs using drill

Tags: mysql, hadoop, distributed-computing, rdbms, apache-drill

If I use apache drill and connect to a RDBMS like MySQL will I be able to utilize full SQL syntax (like `UPDATE/INSERT`)?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30542932/1319519) answer regarding `UPDATE/INSERT` on HDFS, wonder if these is any difference when using drill with RDBMSs.

Comment: I just googled your title & 'apache' and got "Supported SQL Commands". How does the relevant documentation not answer your question?

Comment: @philipxy guess my question is regarding if the "Supported SQL Commands" is universal for all storage-plugins or somehow depend on the underlying data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not supported. You can think of Drill as a SQL engine, not a database. A SQL engine is intended to execute a select statement on a large amount of data as quickly as possible so that the user can answer a question about their data. A database is a SQL engine with extra data management functionality like inserts and updates.

Typically people use Drill on data that is no longer changing. For example if you are running a website and you have data about user activity yesterday. That dataset is no longer changing but you can execute SQL on that data to answer your questions.